# Error: Invalid arguments: wallet not provided

Tags: web3.js, transaction-instructions, magiceden

got error with anchor:
Error occurred: Error: Invalid arguments: wallet not provided.
It is a problem with my low-level deposit instruction, here is the code:

```
  const depositInstruction = await magicEdenProgram.methods
  .deposit({
    escrowPaymentBump: 253,
    amount: "a6aee6",
  })
  .accounts({
    wallet: keypair.publicKey,
    notary: "NTYeYJ1wr4bpM5xo6zx5En44SvJFAd35zTxxNoERYqd",
    escrowPaymentAccount: "6CsmuHtBmguufBVnYNG7WrsLz2ud5SnzesPLYhCTx1sZ",
    authority: "autMW8SgBkVYeBgqYiTuJZnkvDZMVU2MHJh9Jh7CSQ2",
    auctionHouse: "E8cU1WiRWjanGxmn96ewBgk9vPTcL6AEZ1t6F6fkgUWe",
    systemProgram: "11111111111111111111111111111111",
  })
  .instruction();
```

but i have logged wallet - all is good
here is my anchor configuration:

```
const keypair = getWallet(".private/secretKey.json");
const meidl = readJsonFile("src/magic-eden/m2idl.json");
const wallet: Wallet = new Wallet(keypair);
const connection = new Web3.Connection(
Web3.clusterApiUrl("mainnet-beta"),
"confirmed",
);
const provider = new AnchorProvider(connection, wallet, {});
const magicEdenProgram = new Program(
meidl as Idl,
new PublicKey(MAGIC_EDEN_V2_PROGRAM_ID),
provider,
);
```

with another instruction i got the same error:

```
  const buyTxInstruction = await magicEdenProgram.methods.
  buyV2({ buyerPrice, tokenSize, buyerStateExpiry, buyerCreatorRoyaltyBp })
  .accounts(
    {
      wallet: provider.wallet.publicKey,
      notary: "NTYeYJ1wr4bpM5xo6zx5En44SvJFAd35zTxxNoERYqd",
      tokenMint: "3TSQxLkHZq3Amy7eDMJYqPZYs8e6izVLdkLt8h1PYwZ4",
      metadata: "3xh3JLeBZRU9PwSRJwsYrUT1exCEdRby6aYy24SQ5gQf",
      escrowPaymentAccount: "6CsmuHtBmguufBVnYNG7WrsLz2ud5SnzesPLYhCTx1sZ",
      authority: "autMW8SgBkVYeBgqYiTuJZnkvDZMVU2MHJh9Jh7CSQ2",
      auctionHouse: "E8cU1WiRWjanGxmn96ewBgk9vPTcL6AEZ1t6F6fkgUWe",
      buyerTradeState: "FFaxcPjR5QpSDsE1dDU97L6wBGWwUtaB3HYEysdsbGov",
      buyerReferral: "C18EicZUfDQ1rzW6fWxzBwRsmF4VzomUeu8Cfuxn6CZx",
      tokenProgram: "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
      systemProgram: "11111111111111111111111111111111",
    })
  .instruction();
```

Comment: I would try to log the provider and provider wallet to the console and debug from there.